# Rest endpoint not working post Spring boot v3.2.1 migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, single-page-application

I am in the process of moving all my existing spring boot applications from version `2.7.4` to `3.2.1`.

I've one weird observation. All the endpoints ending with `/` are not accessible from UI as well as from postman post migration

For example, this is an existing controller with one simple GET endpoint:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TodosController {
    @GetMapping("/locations")
    public List<Integer> findAllCoordinates(){
        return List.of(10,15);
    }
}
```

now the `GET /api/v1/locations/` doesn’t match anymore and is resulting in an `HTTP 404` error.

However, `GET /api/v1/locations` works. The same problem is there with other endpoints as well. is it a bug in Spring Boot 3 or intentional behaviour has been changed?

Comment: That is because there is no automatic trailing slash handling anymore. So `/api/v1/locations/` is a route with no matching endpoint giving an 404, while in the v2 this route is handled as if there were no trailing slash. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-mvc-and-webflux-url-matching-changes

Comment: Maybe you also wanna take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76895694/13609359

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was considered a security vulnerability and has been the expected behaviour since Spring 6.0.0. See the [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28552).

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by @Valerji is the appropriate one. The behavior of the spring had changed to mitigate security vulnerability. However, if you can't make this change immediately to clients invoking your endpoints (from User interface, other applications, etc), for backward compatibility, the following change can be made to app configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer config) {
        config.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
    }

}
```

**Please Note:** It would be a best practice to make changes to all the clients as soon as possible and use the default configuration.