Getting 401 on migrating to Spring-security 6
I was using an older version of springboot where the spring security was using WebSecurityConfigAdapter and the below mentioned code was working fine.
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
     http
     .httpBasic()
     .and()
     .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .mvcMatchers("/version").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/api/v1/{personId}/**").permitAll()
}

I moved to Spring Security 6 and spring boot 3.2 and WebSecurityConfigAdapter is deprecated.
Handled it as :
fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
            http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf { csrf -> csrf.disable() }
                .authorizeHttpRequests { auth -> 
                            auth.requestMatchers("/version").permitAll()
                            auth.requestMatchers("/swagger-v3/api-docs").permitAll()
    }
}

Initially I had a testcase where my version endpoint was working fine with both "/version" and "/version/".
But now for "/version/" I am getting a 401. Similarly getting 401 for /swagger-v3/api-docs as well.
Could someone help in understanding what changed or how can I fix it ?

Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76895694
